# iPhone audio playback: force through internal speaker?

Tags: iphone, audio

Does anyone know if it is possible to implement playback of an audio file through the internal speaker even if the headphones are plugged in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are doing your audio playback, but try having a look at the "Redirecting Output Audio" section of the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide.pdf)

It looks something like this:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;  // 1 
AudioSessionSetProperty ( 
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,                         // 2 
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),                                      // 3 
    &audioRouteOverride                                               // 4 
);
```

Comment: Does this change the route for the input as well?
I want to take input from external mic and want to use the internal speakers for the output. Can I do that using this method?

Comment: I'm not sure, when you say external mic, do you mean the device microphone instead of a headset microphone?

Comment: No no I meant the mic that is externally plugged in. The input should be taken from that. I got my issue resolved. Found your post very helpful!

Comment: @slf i want to record sound that is played in background using AudioPlayer,at same time i want to disable External noise(External mic). is this Possible???

Comment: @Aelish from what it sounds like, you need to watch use audio queue services and monitor it for information.  You don't actually want to 'record' anything at all so the microphone is irrelevant.  I don't know if the audio data is available if you don't have a handle to the queue, in other words, I don't know if you can record audio from say, music playing in iTunes or Pandora on the device

Comment: @Namratha Have you found how to have audio route to speaker but record from headset microphone ?

Comment: I have seen this solution several times but I just do not know where to place that piece of code. Can Someone please tell me?

Comment: I want to do the opposite: when the Apple-supplied headphones (that have a built-in mic) are plugged into the iPhone I want to use the device's built-in mic (not the mic on the headphone) while listening to audio through the headphones (not the receiver or speaker built-in to the device). Any ideas on how to do this? It seems like it would be similar to your solution.

Comment: @Nick For a route change event, the system sends the [kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) in the inID parameter

Comment: @Nick route change apple example: [AddMusic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think this is not possible, as there seems to be some kind of mechanical switch, which indicates a plugged in headset thus preventing speaker output when this is the case.
(read [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4327217?tstart=0))

Some other hints can be found in the description of `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker`: 
"Specifies whether or not to route audio to the speaker (instead of to the receiver) when no other audio route, such as a headset, is connected."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for anyone arriving here since the `AudioSessionSetProperty` (and related APIs) have been deprecated in iOS 7.0.

```
- (BOOL)setupSpeakerRouteOverride {
    NSError *avAudioErr = nil;
    BOOL result = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                   overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                   error:&avAudioErr];
    if (avAudioErr) {
        // Handle Error
        NSLog(@"Error setting speaker route override: %@",[avAudioErr localizedDescription]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

1. This is part of the `AVAudioSession` API and the relevant Apple documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616443-overrideoutputaudioport?language=objc).
2. Important notes from the API discussion section:

> If your app uses the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category,
> calling this method with the AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker option
> causes the system to route audio to the built-in speaker and
> microphone regardless of other settings. This change remains in effect
> only until the current route changes or you call this method again
> with the AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone option.
>
> If you’d prefer to permanently enable this behavior, you should
> instead set the category’s
> AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker option. Setting this
> option routes to the speaker rather than the receiver if no other
> accessory such as headphones are in use.

3. If the temporary nature of the override is appropriate for your application, you could react to audio route changes by subscribing to the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` notification and handle the events accordingly. (See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessionroutechangenotification).)
4. For a similar solution is Swift, see this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50106322/2333933).