# AVAudioPlayer Output to Speaker

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

After searching around for how to send `AVAudioPlayer` output to the iPhone's speaker, I found this:

[iPhone audio playback: force through internal speaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064846/iphone-audio-playback-force-through-internal-speaker)

Despite setting the category correctly to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, this solution doesn't seem to be working for me and won't even let the build compile, giving me this error:

```
"_AudioSessionSetProperty", referenced from:

...
...

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I not including something? I'm importing `AudioToolbox`, `AVFoundation`, and `CoreAudio`.

My class implements `AVAudioSessionDelegate`, `AVAudioRecorderDelegate`, `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`, and `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Never mind, it looks like AudioToolbox WASN'T actually added.

Answer (score 0):

Add the AudioToolbox and AVFoundation frameworks to your project by Right-Cliking on Frameworks -> Add -> Existing Frameworks