# sound from speakers while audio jack is in

Tags: objective-c, xcode

We are MFi at apple.

we need to connect an audioJack to pass digital data(as we do now) via microphone, but we need to output the sounds from the iphone at the same time .

is it possible technically? or does the audioJack is disconnect two points in it ?

i know the MAC can output sounds while audioJack is in.

has anyone tried ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to record from the line-in (audio jack) whilst playing sounds from the built-in speakers at the same time. I don't think you will have much joy, based upon these past questions:

[Force iPhone to output through the speaker, while recording from headphone mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175082/force-iphone-to-output-through-the-speaker-while-recording-from-headphone-mic)

[iPhone audio playback: force through internal speaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064846/iphone-audio-playback-force-through-internal-speaker)

Comment: THANKS , have read that, but my goal was not to get signal from the built in mic, but as you said from the audioJack line in, so there is no feedback problem. there is a code in your second post, but i am not really sure what he does,and where to put it.