# Force play audio file through iPhone speakers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio

Is it possible to force a audio file to play through the iPhone speakers even if headphones are plugged in?

Comment: I very much hope not! Why would you want to force that on your user? I would delete your app immediately if it started blurting audio when I expected it would be silently channeled to my headphones.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064846/iphone-audio-playback-force-through-internal-speaker

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Short answer No. Sorry. I tried to find something like this once but no luck. Apple is pretty vaige about this things.

Answer (score 12):

See [Audio Session Cookbook: Redirecting Output Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW13). Briefly,

1. Set the category to kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord
2. Set kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute to kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker

If that doesn't work, then there probably isn't a way to do it.