# Audio Session Services: kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute with different routes for input & output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm messing around with Audio Session Services. I'm trying to control the audio routes setting `AudioSessionSetProperty:` `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` as `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker`.

The problem is that it changes the route both for input and output. What I want is to have input set from headset's mic, and output by speakers.

Any ideas?

Ty!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Was reading up and came across this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064846/iphone-audio-playback-force-through-internal-speaker Is this what you have tried?

Comment: Actually that is what ive tried. I still couldnt find the way to separate speaker and mic routes. Pls let me know if you make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in iOS 5 with the properties:

```
kAudioSessionProperty_InputSource 
kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestination
```

For the possible values (what sources \ destinations are available on the device) use AudioSessionGetProperty with the properties:

```
kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources
kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestinations
```

For iOS 3.1+, I assume you're using the PlayAndRecord audio session category - you might want to try setting kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker to true.  For instance,

```
UInt32 defaultToSpeaker = 1;
status = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,                        
                                sizeof (defaultToSpeaker),                                   
                                &defaultToSpeaker                               
                                );
```

Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I don't think you can come closer in < iOS 5.

Comment: Unfortunately, kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources is for **USB audio accessory**. So it not works with my headset.

Comment: I have seen this solution several times but I just do not know where to place that piece of code. Can Someone please tell me?