# iOS: Route audio-IN thru jack, audio-OUT thru inbuilt speaker

Tags: ios, audio, routes, microphone, speaker

My project involves a magnetic card reader device that plugs into the phono socket (ie only uses microphone)

Can I get my project to output sound through the inbuilt speaker while simultaneously listening for input from the device?

Research suggests this is not possible:

[iPhone audio playback: force through internal speaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064846/iphone-audio-playback-force-through-internal-speaker)

[Force iPhone to output through the speaker, while recording from headphone mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175082/force-iphone-to-output-through-the-speaker-while-recording-from-headphone-mic)

[Audio Session Services: kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute with different routes for input & output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048545/audio-session-services-kaudiosessionproperty-overrideaudioroute-with-different)

The only way round I can see is actually changing the audio session every time I wish to emit a sound.

Is this really the only option? And is it practical to do this? How long would it take for the audio session to reconfigure itself?