# iOS 6 Audio multi-route - use external microphone AND internal speaker simultaneously

Tags: ios6, core-audio, microphone

This presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/core-audioios6portland on Core Audio in iOS6 seems to suggest (slide 87) that it is possible to over-ride the automatic output / input of audio devices using Av Session.

So, specifically, it is possible to have an external mic.plugged into an iOS6 device and output sound through the internal speaker ? I've seen this asked before on this site: [iOS: Route audio-IN thru jack, audio-OUT thru inbuilt speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739225/ios-route-audio-in-thru-jack-audio-out-thru-inbuilt-speaker) but no answer was forthcoming.

Many thanks !

Comment: AFAIK, not in iOS 6.1.x or earlier (hint) via any public API.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's documentation:

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/overrideOutputAudioPort:error:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVAudioSessionPortOverride
```

You can override to the speaker, but if you look more closely at the C based Audio Session services (which is actually being deprecated, but still has helpful information) reference:

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Property_Identifiers
```

> If a headset is plugged in at the time you set this property’s value
>   to kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker, the system changes the
>   audio routing for input as well as for output: input comes from the
>   built-in microphone; output goes to the built-in speaker.

I would suggest looking at the documentation for iOS 7 to see if they've added any new functionality. I'd also suggest running tests with external devices like iRiffPort or USB based inputs (if you have an iPad with CCK).