# Override output audio port in iOS 11.3

Tags: avfoundation, avaudiosession

Is it possible to override audio port to speaker(

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil]
```

) when device is connected to external screen via airplay, it worked on iOS 11.2 and earlier, but on iOS 11.3 it doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience that's not enough: you also have to set the AVAudioSession category to `playAndRecord`. This is suggested in the [docs for the `overrideOutputAudioPort:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616443-overrideoutputaudioport) method:

> If your app uses the `playAndRecord` category, calling this method with the `AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker` causes the system to route audio to the built-in speaker and microphone regardless of other settings. This change remains in effect only until the current route changes or you call this method again with the `AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none` option.
>
> If you would prefer
> to permanently enable this behavior, you should instead set the
> category's `defaultToSpeaker` option. Setting this option will always
> route to the speaker rather than receiver if no other accessory such
> as headphones are in use.

Note that those docs specify that that is sufficient. I don't know if it's necessary: I just haven't found other options that work as reliably.

However, the [docs for `defaultToSpeaker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/1616462-defaulttospeaker) do say that it's only usable with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category.

So, doing the following works for me:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
} catch {
    print("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```