# How to switch to earSpeaker programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, vlc, avaudiosession

I am currently playing an audio file with "MobileVlcKit" and I need to switch to earSpeaker (top speaker for phone calls) in the middle of playing audio file.
Currently I am using this code:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
```

But it keep playing from main speaker.
Do anyone knows what is my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923011/override-output-audio-port-in-ios-11-3 !?

Comment: Did not help :( The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my 2 years old objective-c code, not sure will it work for you, but worth to try. here is its swift version:

```swift
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setActive(false)
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
    // handle error
    print(error)
}
```